# Stop auto popping up intellij messages window

Tags: intellij-idea, message

Every time I try to run a test or compile code in IntelliJ, if another file has a compile error, it causes the messages window to auto popup and the editor automatically opens that file with the error. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to disable the **Automatically show first error in editor** option:

[image: show first error]

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work. The problem really is that we have the plugins directory in our project structure (not the default .plugins) in a grails project and some of the plugin's test code has some errors.

Comment: Right, but I think the reason they are in there (I didn't set this project up) are in case we need to make changes to the source, so I think we want to recompile changes.

Comment: You can remove them from excludes once the code is fixed and compiles.

Comment: Yeah that's probably the best solution

Comment: This will just disable scrolling to the source but won't prevent the window from popping up.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AdamArold check the answer date, back in 2012 it worked like that. If the behavior is different now, please submit a new question or report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.